# Rotate array using python as one block binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one array like `[4, 255, 16]`, with `dtype = int8`. I want to rotate it left but like a binary rotate.

I want my array to be as explained below:

```
000001001111111100010000
```

After rotate left 2 bits, it will be:

```
000100111111110001000000
```

In decimal like `[17, 252, 64]`

Comment: Did you try anything already? It is always better when we have some code as starting point.

Comment: Shouldn't `000100111111110001000000` be `[19, 252, 64]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `deque` from `collections` if you want to rotate it nicely,

```
>>> from array import array
>>> from collections import deque
>>> x = array('l', [4, 255, 16])
>>> x
array('l', [4, 255, 16])
>>> z = ''.join([format(y, 'b').zfill(8) for y in x.tolist()])
>>> z
'000001001111111100010000'
>>> d = deque(z)
>>> d.rotate(-2)
>>> ''.join(d)
'000100111111110001000000'
>>> k = ''.join(d)
>>> [int(k[i:i+8],2) for i in range(0, len(k), 8)]
[19, 252, 64]
```

Comment: Why use `array`? `z = ''.join([format(y, 'b').zfill(8) for y in x])` if `x= [4, 255, 16]` works just fine.

Comment: @DavidBuck I just wanted to show the user, if he already has an `array`. And the question, started with, `I have one array like [4, 255, 16], with dtype = int8`. Which is `array.array('l', [4, 255, 16])` :)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answers.  Though, can be remove `.tolist()` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sure, he could have just started with a simple `list`

Answer (score 1):

You want to rotate the array as if it were one long integer.

The solution below converts the array into one long integer, that is simply a Python `int`, rotates it with bitwise arithmetic, then write it back in the array.

### Code

```
from array import array

def shift_left(arr, shift=1):
    if not arr:
        return

    long = 0
    itemsize = arr.itemsize * 8
    bit_length = len(arr) * itemsize
    item_bits = (1 << itemsize) - 1
    bits = (1 << bit_length) - 1

    # Convert the array to a long integer
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(arr)):
        long |= x << (i * itemsize)

    # Left part of the | shifts the long left and drops the overflow
    # Right part of the | adds the last bits at the start of the long
    long = (long << shift & bits) | long >> (bit_length - shift)

    # Write back the long integer in the array
    for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
        arr[-i] = long & item_bits
        long >>= itemsize
```

### Example

```
arr = array('B', [4, 255, 16])
shift_left(arr, shift=2)
print(arr)
```

### Output

```
array('B', [19, 252, 64])
```